# Action Script 3 touch drag with hitTest

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, air, hittest

I'm using Action Script 3 to make android game using "air for android"

I make a ball, gole and StatusTxt.

and i have end every thing in the design Correctly.

in the Code:

```
  Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.TOUCH_POINT; 
ball.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_BEGIN, onTouchBegin); 
ball.addEventListener(TouchEvent.TOUCH_END, onTouchEnd);

function onTouchBegin(e:TouchEvent) { 
    e.target.startTouchDrag(e.touchPointID);
}  
function onTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent) { 
    e.target.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID); 
}

if(gole.hitTestObject(ball))
        {
            StatusTxt.text = "You hit it.";
        }
```

but the StatusTxt has not changed Why??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is outside the event. You could add it in the `onTouchEnd` function. If you want to test it outside of the `TOUCH_END` event you could use a `ENTER_FRAME` event.

So it would end up looking something like this:

```
function onTouchEnd(e:TouchEvent) 
{
        e.target.stopTouchDrag(e.touchPointID); 

        if(gole.hitTestObject(ball))
        {
            StatusTxt.text = "You hit it.";
        }
}
```

or with the `ENTER_FRAME` like this:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function onEnterFrame(e:Event) : void
{
        if(gole.hitTestObject(ball))
        {
            StatusTxt.text = "You hit it.";
        }
}
```

Comment: Thank you i have search about this about 2 hour.